# Running unit tests in a test suite (with each test as an individual test script)

Tags: python, testing

I am aware of running multiple tests defined as individual tests inside a unittest Class but I am trying to see how I can run the unit tests that exist as individual script files as a test suite. My scripts are in Python.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a little more clear?  do you want to run a single test function from a `unittest.TestCase` subclass?  or you want to run a suite of individual `unittest.TestCase`s?

Comment: The latter - run a suite of individual unittest.TestCase s.

Comment: Are they all in the same file?  Different files?  Why not just write another script which imports all of the unittest.TestCase's and then calls unittest.main() at the end?

Comment: How exactly can I do the option you are talking about? I have unit_test_1.py and unit_test_2.py .. but to import these two into another file, I would need "__init__.py" inside that directory where I have the other above 2 scripts.. Is that right?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python

import unit_test_1
import unit_test_2


if __name__ == '__main__':

    unit_test_1.unittest.main()
    unit_test_2.unittest.main() -> The code here does not seem to run any tests..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`nose`](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) -- it can automatically find unit tests. Or, you could write your own test suite loader, such as

```
import unittest
import sys
import os
import glob

__usage__ = '''
%prog      # Searches CWD
%prog DIR
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unit_dir = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    os.chdir(unit_dir)
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    for filename in glob.glob('test_*.py'):
        modname = filename[:-3]
        module = __import__(modname)
        suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(module))

    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Running

```
script.py /path/to/directory
```

searches for files of the form `test_*.py`, imports it as a module then loads
any tests if finds in the module.

Comment: Not sure with nose how I would pass my config file which I would usually pass while running them standalone (single unit test script)

Comment: My question above, about passing the config file is with respect to your sample code above.

Comment: I dont have code specific to unit testing. My script has the usual "setUp, tearDown and testxxxx" in the script but they run with a config file passed as a CLI parameter. I am trying to see how I can run multiple unit tests and get some results. Looks like "nose" needs "nose-testconfig" for me to use a config file (for passing test params)